# Discord.py How to fix "Phantom code?" (Previous, and now deleted, chunks of code still being run along with new code)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot and one of my commands reads like this

```
@client.command()
async def sus(ctx):
    await ctx.send('⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣠⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣶⣦⣤⣄⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀\n⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣴⣿⡿⠛⠉⠙⠛⠛⠛⠛⠻⢿⣿⣷⣤⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀\n⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣼⣿⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⣀⠈⢻⣿⣿⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀\n⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣸⣿⡏⠀⠀⠀⣠⣶⣾⣿⣿⣿⠿⠿⠿⢿⣿⣿⣿⣄⠀⠀⠀\n⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿⠁⠀⠀⢰⣿⣿⣯⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠙⢿⣷⡄⠀\n⠀⠀⣀⣤⣴⣶⣶⣿⡟⠀⠀⠀⢸⣿⣿⣿⣆⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⣷⠀\n⠀⢰⣿⡟⠋⠉⣹⣿⡇⠀⠀⠀⠘⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷⣦⣤⣤⣤⣶⣶⣶⣶⣿⣿⣿⠀\n⠀⢸⣿⡇⠀⠀⣿⣿⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠹⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠃⠀\n⠀⣸⣿⡇⠀⠀⣿⣿⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠻⠿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠿⠿⠛⢻⣿⡇⠀⠀\n⠀⠸⣿⣧⡀⠀⣿⣿⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿⠃⠀⠀\n⠀⠀⠛⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣰⣿⣿⣷⣶⣶⣶⣶⠶⠀⢠⣿⣿⠀⠀⠀\n⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿⡇⠀⣽⣿⡏⠁⠀⠀⢸⣿⡇⠀⠀⠀\n⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿⡇⠀⢹⣿⡆⠀⠀⠀⣸⣿⠇⠀⠀⠀\n⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢿⣿⣦⣄⣀⣠⣴⣿⣿⠁⠀⠈⠻⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠏⠀⠀⠀⠀\n⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠛⠻⠿⠿⠿⠿⠋⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀')
```

The bot is supposed to send an among us copypasta, but instead, it returns the copypasta with an added word of "sussy". Before I added the copy pasta, I had "sussy" as a place holder. But even after I deleted it the bot still uses it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[Here is link to example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef3EB.jpg) (No coded was changed between the 2 commands shown)

(this also happens with another command)

(The messages will show up at different times during the function)

(I am relatively new to stackoverflow so sorry if this question is formatted poorly)

Comment: This was happening to me because I was rewriting my bot and VSCode imported sections from my old code automatically via `import` statements and I never noticed. Is the same thing happening to you?

Comment: add me and I can help you out: `Libra#1337` it's hard to tell what's going on without your repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting your computer should work. I think the issue is that your old bot is still running in the background. Does the "sussy" also appears when your bot is not running ?

Otherwise, there is probably somewhere else in your code a function on_message or something that is executed at the same time as the command (maybe the command in another cog with the same name ?) you could also try to delete the pycache folder, but usually there should not be any phantom code.

Comment: I'm just going to say that you could also access Task Manager through CTRL + ALT + DEL to just end the Python Process.